# NaN as a result of using tapply, when calculating means

Tags: r, tapply

Checked a lot of, there are similar questions, but cannot understand one simple thing. I am trying to calculate mean salaries for different baseball positions.

```
library(Lahman)
library(tidyverse)

data("Fielding")
data(Salaries)

# First, I need to merge two datasets
merged.df <- merge(Fielding, Salaries, by = "playerID", na.rm = TRUE)
merged.df.2002 <- merged.df[merged.df$yearID.x == "2002",]

# Let's try tapply
mean.salary <- tapply(merged.df.2002$POS, merged.df.2002$salary, mean, na.rm = TRUE)
# So it gives me an error
# In mean.default(X[[i]], ...) :
#  argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA

class(merged.df.2002$POS)
class(merged.df.2002$salary)

# Very likely POS column is factor for some reason.
# Coerce them through 
merged.df.2002$POS <- as.numeric(as.character(merged.df.2002$POS))
# Warning message:
# NAs introduced by coercion 
merged.df.2002$salary <- as.numeric(as.character(merged.df.2002$salary))
#as.numeric(merged.df.2002$salary)
class(merged.df.2002$salary)

# Let's try tapply again
mean.salary <- tapply(merged.df.2002$POS, merged.df.2002$salary, mean, na.rm 
= TRUE)
mean.salary

60000   62500   63500   65000   67000   67500   68000   68750   70000   
71000   72500   77500   78000   80000   82000   82500 
NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     
NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
```

Any ideas? Many thanks!

Comment: The mean of an empty set is NaN. In particular mean(NA, na.rm=TRUE) is NaN.

Comment: Less related: `na.rm` is not an argument to the `merge` function.

Comment: @Hugh, many thanks for your super fast answer, so where is my mistake in this flow?

Comment: On my phone, but my approach would be: where is mean used with na.rm? In those instances, are all the values in a particular group NA? Have I attempted to take the mean of a set after discarding all elements?

Comment: you don't want `na.rm` in your merge; see the `all.x` and `all.y` arguments, which you're probably after

Comment: Guys, many thanks for all your responses. But when I remove na.rm, I get 60000   62500   63500   65000   67000   67500   68000   68750   70000   71000   72500   77500   78000   80000   82000   82500   85000   86000 
     NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it was easy, but I screwed up

```
merged.df <- merge(Fielding, Salaries) 
# So, my mistake was that I merged only by playerid.

merged.df.2002 <- merged.df[merged.df$yearID == 2002, ] 
# we pick 2002 year from the merged dataset

# use tapply for mean
merged.df.mean <- tapply(merged.df.2002$salary, merged.df.2002$POS, mean, 
na.rm = TRUE)

#      1B      2B      3B       C      OF       P      SS 
# 2543845 1400543 1547836 1787933 2659230 2150887 1979732
```